# A special case of editing regex expressions in a sam file

Tags: sed, bioinformatics, cut

I have a sam file where I need to edit each line that begins in a @SQ at the start of the file and every line in the second section with the alignment information. For those who are not familiar with the sam format, my file is structured like this:

```
@SQ     SN:fig|165597.4.peg.6247|CwatDRAFT_0723|VBICroWat128338_6247|Flavin     LN:630
@SQ     SN:fig|165597.4.peg.6248|CwatDRAFT_0914|VBICroWat128338_6248|hypothetical       LN:534
etc... and then after thousands of lines in the same format it contains text formatted as below:

A00521:365:HWWTFDSX3:4:1101:10719:13667 147     fig|1164990.3.peg.2356|RintRC_3345|4-hydroxybenzoatepolyprenyltransferase(EC2.5.1.39)@Cyanobacterialpolyprenyltransferase(UbiAhomolog)        187     26      17S16M55S       =       187     -16     TCAAAGGTTACCCGGACCTTTCGGTCAAGGTTGTAGACTCGTTGAGTGCA                TCAGTGTAGCGCGCGTGCGGCCCAGAACATCTAAGGGC  FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF:FFFFFFFFFF        NM:i:0  AS                :i:16   XS:i:14
. . . also repeated thousands of times for different genes.
```

I need to edit this file so that every time there is a string with the following format:
fig|xxxxxxxx|xxxxxxx|xxxxxxxx|xxx everything from the second pipe onwards to the end of that group of text is removed. This would reformat the above text to be:

```
@SQ     SN:fig|165597.4.peg.6247  LN:630
@SQ     SN:fig|165597.4.peg.6248  LN:534 ... 

A00521:365:HWWTFDSX3:4:1101:10719:13667 147     fig|1164990.3.peg.2356    187     26      17S16M55S       =       187     -16     TCAAAGGTTACCCGGACCTTTCGGTCAAGGTTGTAGACTCGTTGAGTGCA                TCAGTGTAGCGCGCGTGCGGCCCAGAACATCTAAGGGC  FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF:FFFFFFFFFF        NM:i:0  AS                :i:16   XS:i:14
```

I know that sed or cut is probably my best bet but am very unsure how to structure the command. I figured out that

```
sed 's/|[^|]*//2g' sed_test.sam > out.sam
```

will remove everything after the second | on each line but I need to keep the information after the end of the expression containing the pipes (i.e. the LN:__ fields and the numbers in the second section).

Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue!

```bash
perl -ne '
    for (split /(\s+)/) {
        s/^([^|]*[|][^|]*)[|].*/$1/ if /[|]/;
        print;
    }' -- file
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line and runs the code for each line;
- [split](https://perldoc.pl/split) splits each line on whitespace, as there's a capture group (parentheses around `\s+`), the whitespace is also part of the returned substrings;
- if the part contains a vertical bar, everything from the second vertical bar is removed;
- finally, each part is printed - only parts containing vertical bars will be changed.

Answer (score 0):

When working with tab-separated fields, [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) might be a better choice. Here's one way:

```
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="\t"
}
{
    f = (/^@/ ? (/^@SQ/ ? 2 : 0) : 3)
    if(f) {
        split($f, a, "|")
        $f = a[1] "|" a[2]
    }
    print
}
```

You could put the above in a file called `script.awk` and run it using:

```
awk -f script.awk file.sam
```

However, you may simply prefer the "one-liner":

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" } { f = (/^@/ ? (/^@SQ/ ? 2 : 0) : 3); if(f) { split($f, a, "|"); $f = a[1] "|" a[2] } }1' file.sam
```

This sets the input and output field separators to a tab character. Then, for  each line of input, it uses a ternary operator to select the field number to transform. If the line starts with an *@* character, we use another ternary to select the second column if the line starts with *@SQ*. If the line doesn't start with an *@* character, we select the third column to transform. If we found a column to transform, split the field on the pipe character into an array and replace the field with the first two elements of the array again separated using a pipe character. Print all line records.

Answer (score 0):

You basically save nothing using intervals

> ```
> mawk '!/^[@]SQ / || NF=NF' FS='[^|]+\|[^|]+\|[^|]+[ \t]+'
> gawk '!/^[@]SQ / || NF=NF'  FS='([^|]+[|]){2}[^|]+[ \t]+'
> ```

```
@SQ     SN:fig|165597.4.peg.6247| LN:630
@SQ     SN:fig|165597.4.peg.6248| LN:534
etc... and then after thousands of lines in the same format it contains text formatted as below:

A00521:365:HWWTFDSX3:4:1101:10719:13667 147     fig|1164990.3.peg.2356|RintRC_3345|4-hydroxybenzoatepolyprenyltransferase(EC2.5.1.39)@Cyanobacterialpolyprenyltransferase(UbiAhomolog)        187     26      17S16M55S       =       187     -16     TCAAAGGTTACCCGGACCTTTCGGTCAAGGTTGTAGACTCGTTGAGTGCA                TCAGTGTAGCGCGCGTGCGGCCCAGAACATCTAAGGGC  FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF:FFFFFFFFFF        NM:i:0  AS                :i:16   XS:i:14
. . . also repeated thousands of times for different genes.
```